# How to use ASP.NET to connect to a remote Oracle database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, nhibernate, oracle10g, connection-string

I have Oracle (10g Express Edition) installed on one pc.

Visual Studio 2008 SP1 is installed on another pc.

I want to run an ASP.NET web app that uses the remote database. The two PCs are connected by a LAN (wired) connection. How can I connect to the database? What will the connection string be? The operating system on both PCs is Windows XP.

Comment: http://connectionstrings.com/

Answer (score 2):

A lot of that will depend on what driver you're using. If you take a look at [this site](http://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle), you should get an idea of the connection string you'd need for whatever database driver you choose.

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

```
string strConnectionString= "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION="
             + "(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=_YOUR_SERVER_NAME_)(PORT=_YOUR_SERVER_PORT_)))"
             + "(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=_YOUR_SERVICE_NAME_)));"
             + "User Id=YourUserID;Password=YourPassword;";
```